# Connection to PostgreSQL with Python 3 does not work: create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, scrapy, python-3.6

I followed [this](http://newcoder.io/scrape/) tutorial to learn about web scraping with scrapy. Many parts are outdated though, even after checking open [pull requests](https://github.com/econchick/new-coder/pulls?page=1&q=is%3Apr%20is%3Aopen) against the project I had a few issues. I did follow through though and started the project again with Python 3 (instead of 2.7) and up to date components. I read a bit in the scrapy docs and got it to work with one of my sites of interest, there is one issue though.

## Question

**models.py** contains the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

import settings

def db_connect():
    return create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))
```

This gives a `NameError: name 'settings' is not defined` when run with `scrapy crawl my_spider -o items.json`

Trying another solution suggested here on StackExchange:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

def db_connect():
    settings = get_project_settings()
    return create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))
```

Results in: `AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'DATABASE'`

After ironing out all the other bugs successfully I had to replace the code.

```
    return create_engine("postgresql://scrape:123456@localhost:5432/scrape")
```

This works, everyting else is fine. Can someone tell me please what is the recommended approach to source the information and build the connection string? I'd prefer to keep configuration data in **settings.py**, but I'm open to other solutions if there is a problem with that. Please share some insight.

settings.py:

```
DATABASE = {
    'drivername': 'postgres',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': '5432',
    'username': 'scrape',
    'password': '123456',
    'database': 'scrape'
}
```

Project overview:

```
├── __init__.py
├── items.py
├── middlewares.py
├── models.py
├── pipelines.py
├── settings.py
└── spiders
    ├── my_spider.py
    └── __init__.py
```

---

Edit: Added `from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL` statement

Answer (score 1):

`DATABASE` is not listed in the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html) and attempts to import it with `import settings` or `import scrapy.settings` have failed. I got it to work with the following code while keeping the data in settings.py:

```
import scrape_tut.settings

def db_connect():
    return create_engine(URL(**myproject.settings.DATABASE))
```